# Create an Online mode and Offline mode application

Tags: ipad, html, grails

I have lot of forms with data being submitted to the system and lot of views with data being pulled from database. I want to convert my web application into online and offline mode. I have gone through HTML5 local storage and web storage concepts and already started
implementing. I had to refactor my code a lot for this.

I am feeling that this approach is not the right one. Does anyone have a better suggestion as to create an application which works both offline and online and can save and retrieve lot of data.

Currently my application is a web application written in Groovy & Grails. My application is intended to be used on all possible browsers and smart devices. Its a Proof of Concept still work in progress and I need guidance on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is still a web technology, and optimized for online usage. Making offline web app, even using HTML5 features, is very limited.

If you're really need full functional offline app, it's better to take a look at desctop/mobile tools. Some of them, like [Apache Cordowa](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) (was PhoneGap) or [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/), can reuse some web techologies, like JavaScript. But it's totally different way, and  you'll need to have 3 version of your app: web (grails), desktop (titanium, or swing maybe) and mobile (cordowa/titanium)

Comment: Is there any architecture optimized for these kind of situations

Comment: Maybe it's 'RESTFul API + webapp/mobileapp on this base'